# Test for a specific item with a coloured name in a chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem to detect an item with coloured name in a chest. I've made an item thru essentials plugin:
/i 352:1 1 name:&f123
So, that name with white colour. But the NBT tag of the name is §f and i can't put this symbol into my command block. How can i detect it? Please, don't advise don't use coloured names.

Comment: What part of that command is the name? What does the command do? Do you want help for a Vanilla command or a mod?

Comment: testforblock ~ ~1 ~ 54 -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:352s,Count:1b,Damage:1s,tag:{display:{Name:"§fAsh of warrior",Lore:["§7§oThere is some black spells applied"]},ench:{id:61s,lvl:1s}}}]}

But i can't put § in the command block for detecting.
I have minecraft server 1.7.2 with plugins (essentials and etc)

Comment: But your client is pure vanilla minecraft without any mods?

Comment: No. We have our custom mod based on vamilla.

Comment: I'm sorry, there were some mistakes with brackets in the command:
testforblock ~ ~1 ~ 54 -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:352s,Count:1b,Damage:1s,tag:{display:{Name:"§fAsh of warrior",Lore:["§7§oThere is some black spells applied"]},ench:[{id:61s,lvl:1s}]}}]}

Comment: Could you add all this information in your original question please.
Also, because this is concerning modded minecraft (while the problem can occure in non modded as well) I'm not sure if your question can and will be answered

Comment: Of course i did. The problem is not in command, but in this symbol § that i can't put in my command block in game.
I can solve it only by using NBTExplorer and put in command block this symbol § and then it works.

Comment: Hang on, is the problem that when you press the § character while inside a command block, the § character isn't entered into the command block textfield? Or is the problem that the character appears, but it doesn't work like it's intended? If it's the former, I don't know how to solve it, but the latter can probably be solved by escaping it (put a \ directly in front of the §).

Comment: It even doesn't appears in textfield. I can't type it any way or paste it from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

According to a number of other answers on this site, Minecraft doesn't support entering a § ingame. You either need the [Text Formatting mod](http://spacechase0.com/mods/minecraft/text-formatting/) installed on your server, or you need to enter this data using an external program.

For more information on the Section Sign, check out https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes

Comment: Yeah, i did that thru the NBTexplorer, but it takes much time. So, if there is no way to enter it ingame except using external programs, then it doesn't fit. Anyway, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @ПавелМакаров As I said, you can also install the Text Formatting mod (link in the answer) on your server, which allows you to enter the § symbol ingame.